Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?l=dataLayer&
I am working on a chrome extension with React but keep getting this error after unpacking into chrome

Refused to load the script 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?l=dataLayer&id=G-FEDZ04DLF7' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.


Does anyone know what could be the possible issue?
I have tried reloading and creating a new build but still get the same error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
